# How to create sbt plugin for current events of building app?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have this hello world plugin:

```
object HelloPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val sayHello: TaskKey[Unit] = TaskKey("saying hello")
  }

  import autoImport._
  override def projectSettings = Seq(

    sayHello := {
      println("------------------------------------ heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelooooooooo -------------------")
    }
  )

}
```

I'd like using my `sayHello` task before and after compile time. **How can I do it?**

I found [relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415203/sbt-plugin-execute-custom-task-before-compilation), but it's not about AutoPlugin extending.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adapt that answer to your situation. The answer stays the same: use `dependsOn`, but instead of `build.sbt` you add it to your plugin's `projectSettings`:

```
override def projectSettings = Seq(
  sayHello := { ... },
  Compile/compile := (Compile/compile).dependsOn(sayHello).value
)
```

Comment: Great! But I don't understand how I can import `Compile/compile`. `IntelliJ Idea` can't help me. :( Also, can I make something just after compile as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "import `Compile/compile`"? If you're using sbt 0.13, write `compile in Compile` instead. To do something after a task read this: https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Sequential-Task.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `compile` `TaskKey`, like:

```
override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    compile in Compile := Def.taskDyn {
          hello.value // call before
          val c = (compile in Compile).value // actual compilation
          Def.task {
            hello.value // call after
            c
          }
        }.value
)

def hello: Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] = Def.task {
   println("hello")
}
```

Docs: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Dynamic-Task.html#build.sbt+v2